# How to find matching fields in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple databse that I'm using to try to make a job a little easier. There are 2 tables, one with a list of website URLs and the number of visits over the last 6 months. The urls are structured in a certain way:

www.domain.com/server/someotherstuff/123456789012345/pageTemplateName

The long number in the middle is a unique page ID. The other table is a long list of these IDs. I want to run a query that shows the URL and the number of visits for all pages that have an ID in the other table. So I was thinking somehting like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Stats
WHERE  Stats.url LIKE '%' + Pages.PageId + '%'
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are working outside of MS Access or you have changed the options, the wildcard is *, not %

```
SELECT *
FROM Stats, Pages
WHERE  Stats.url LIKE '*' & Pages.PageId & '*'
```

Comment: That's workked a treat. Thanks. I had tried using an asterix as a wildcard before, tried a few different variations and it didin't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can  try like this

```
SELECT * FROM Stats Inner Join Pages on Stats.url LIKE '%' + Pages.PageId + '%'
```